# Codename One: findById in UIFrament

Tags: codenameone

I'm doing some tests with `UIFragment`. Can you please tell me why the following code is wrong? It gives me a `NullPointerException`.

```
Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
UIFragment myUI = UIFragment.parseJSON("{flow: $myFunLabel, align: center}")
        .set("myFunLabel", new Label("Hi World"));
hi.add(myUI.getView());
myUI.findById("myFunLabel").putClientProperty("WhatIsThis?", "This is my fun Label!!!");
hi.show();
Log.p((String) myUI.findById("myFunLabel").getClientProperty("WhatIsThis?"));
```

Thank you

Comment: Is it the parseJSON line that fails? Can you break it down to parts to point at the exact line that returns null?

Comment: `findById` returns null. This can be tested with: `if (myUI.findById("myFunLabel") == null) {Log.p("ERROR: findById returns null!!!");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findById()` only finds components with an `id` attribute.  This is primarily for accessing containers within the fragment hierarchy.  Injected components (e.g. `$componentName`) don't necessarily have IDs.

For example

```
UIFragment myUI = UIFragment.parseJSON("{flow: $myFunLabel, id:myFlow align: center}")
        .set("myFunLabel", new Label("Hi World"));
Container cnt = myUI.findById('myFlow');
```

`cnt` would contain the flow container.

In the JSON notation, there isn't a way, currently, to assign an ID to an injected component (e.g. `$myFunLabel`).  In the XML notation you could assign an ID using:

```
<$myFunLabel id="myFunLabel"/>
```

This omission is mainly because, since the component is injected, you already have access to it, prior to injection.  It is the generated containers in the hierarchy that you wouldn't have access to easily, other than through `findById()`.